# How to make a Google Compute Cloud app visible from a domain not just a raw IP address?

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have deployed an app using google compute cloud which is visible from a raw ephemeral IP address ... How to I link this ephemeral IP to my domain ?

To make this easier I registered the domain ( mydomain.org ) at [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/registrar)

I added a type A Record Set on my managed zone :

```
gcloud dns managed-zones describe  myzone


creationTime: '2016-03-28T23:05:31.385Z'
description: just another zone
dnsName: mydomain.org.
id: '2379583277824599330'
kind: dns#managedZone
name: myzone
nameServers:
- ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
```

from here you can see the raw IP (111.222.333.444) where the app is visible from

```
gcloud dns record-sets list  --zone myzone 

NAME                       TYPE  TTL  DATA
mydomain.org.  A     5    111.222.333.444
mydomain.org.  NS    6    ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com., ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com., ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com., ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
mydomain.org.  SOA   6    ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 1209600 300
```

yet when I do a

```
curl mydomain.org
```

it just responds with (similar from browser)

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mydomain.org
```

yet using the raw IP it correctly connects to the cloud app

```
curl 111.222.333.444
```

here I show some command line DNS lookups

```
nslookup mydomain.org ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
```

output

```
Server:     ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
Address:    216.239.32.110#53

Name:   mydomain.org
Address: 111.222.333.444
```

What am I missing ?  What is the `gcloud dns` command I am missing ?  The process would be :  deploy app to ephemeral IP -> issue unknown command to link this IP to domain ... I want to be able to issue this after each deploy (a fresh ephemeral IP) from my app still in development ... I do not want a Static IP

I deployed the app using command line tools gcloud and kubectl so its a Google Compute (IaaS) app not a Google App Engine (PaaS) app

I did the domain register a few days ago so the domain has propagated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which works across hosting providers generally.  It involves going back and forth between where you created your domain (Domain Registrar) and where you deploy your app :

- create your domain at your Domain Registrar ... ignore its list of Name Servers ... you will be replacing the original list with a fresh ***LIST***
- wherever you deploy your app will supply ability to define some kind of DNS hosting zone ... create a new zone for your domain which will auto populate a fresh ***LIST*** of Name Servers ... copy this ***LIST***
- go back to your Domain Registrar and update its Name Servers for your domain (record type NS) with that ***LIST***
- deploy your app which will reveal a fresh new IP
- get into the DNS hosting zone and update your Type A record with this new IP

Answer (score 1):

Since the Cloud DNS nameservers appear to be happy to resolve the domain, I'd double-check that Cloud DNS is actually set as the nameservers for your domain:

`$ dig NS mydomain.org.`